# Install module via Drupal Console fails

Tags: 8

I'm trying to install a module via the new Drupal Console on Drupal 8.

I chmodded my modules directory to 777 without success.

```
drupal module:install admin_toolbar

[ERROR] Unable to install modules admin_toolbar due to missing modules admin_toolbar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to download it first and then install.

```
drupal module:download admin_toolbar
drupal module:install admin_toolbar
```

Comment: I feel quite dumb for missing that...

Comment: I think it's a bug to be honest.  Using drush, it'd download and then install, prompting at every point if needed.

Comment: derp, of course this worked, I feel stupid now :)

Comment: @HST, its not a bug it just a feature that was never implemented.  Just because Drush does it, does not mean that Drupal Console is going to do it as well. However, that will be a nice feature to have. I will open an issue for that.

Comment: @HST, I have open an issue to support this functionality see more at - https://github.com/hechoendrupal/DrupalConsole/issues/1710